# Static Google map doesn't show on iOS7.1

Tags: html, google-maps-api-2, ios7.1

I made this static map image-link to put on our website. The map works in Chrome on Mac OS 10.6.8 but it doesn't show on iOS7.1. Ive tried both on iPhone 4s and iPad2. The only thing I get on iOS7 is a blank square.

If I paste the link in the Safari adress-field on my iPad I can see the map.

here's the link:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=62.388298,17.316515&zoom=15&size=300x300&scale=2&markers=color:red%7C62.388298,17.316515&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key=

Since I havent managed to figure this out myself Ive currently made a clickable link for iOS/Android users but Im not sure if Im supposed to do that..

thx

Comment: have you found solution for this? I need the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using the maps api v3? I get the follwing error in chrome on windows:

```
The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.
```

On v3 of the maps api you don´t need a key. 
Eventually this solves your problem.

Comment: Thx, I look into that. V3, thats Javascript right? Time to study a bit then I guess :)

Comment: yes its javascript. There are really really good documentations and examples! take a look: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Hm, I might have managed to fix the static map anyway. I think Id set the wrong adress when I limited where the map could be used. Updating it to a dynamic map might still be a good idea so Ive engaged a friend to help me with that, coding isnt my strong side. But at least I have a working map now

Comment: you could create a fiddle, eventually I can help with the map.